# Old Mac Mini, fans arent working (shuts down due to overheating)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, mac, fan, overheating

I'm currently not able to directly access the machine so I'm sorry to not being able to provide all the details right now but this is the info:

- It is an old Mac Mini.
- It runs Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- It runs as a file server (SMB)

**Problem description:**

The symptom is that it randomly shuts off. Looking through the logs I found that Nouveau reported "critical temperature" right before shut-off.

Steps taken:

- I installed the proprietary nvidia driver, hoping it perhaps could do temperature control better. Did not help.
- I installed `lm-sensor` and ran the `sensors` which showed that the Main Fan RPM was 0 - Lead me to believe it is not running and overheating!
- I ran `sensors-detect` and it suggested I load the `coretemp` module which I did. Fan still at 0 and it is still shutting down.
- I found a suggestion to install `fancontrol` and run the `pwmconfig`. It told me there were no fans to control.
- Found a suggestion to install `macfanctld` and enable that service to run. Did not make the fans turn on and it is still shutting down.

I've run out of ideas on how to fix this issue. I would like to be able to get the fans running so that I can use it for as long as the hardware is working.

Comment: Have you manually checked that the FAN is ok? Try disassembling the case and connect the FAN to an external power source (with the correct voltage) to check if it's ok. If it doesn't move, you've found the error. Sometimes these FANs get polluted or just go defect.

Comment: If nothing has changed recently, it's probably hardware related.